# Is there a way to kill weeds in a brick patio without killing the Moss

Tags: weed-control

Does anyone know how to kill the weeds in my brick patio without killing the Moss. I love the Moss that has started growing in the cracks but it is not mature enough to fight off the weeds yet.

Comment: You may find that the moss is actually contributing to the weed problem: they create an environment in which seeds can germinate and over time will lead to the formation of soil in the gaps.

Answer (score 3):

Most weedkillers intended for use on paths and paving will also kill the moss. However, if your patio receives a lot of shade in winter, but very little in summer, chances are the moss will die out during summer anyway - moss usually starts growing and thriving in cracks when it's mostly shady and damp.

Assuming it won't be in full sun all summer, then you could try using one of these [Garden Hand Weeder](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004Y9YCM0) taking care to avoid the moss:

[image: Gardena 8943-U Garden Hand Weeder]